# How can I allow users to search for other users based on profile information

Tags: users

I have two profiles for my users. First, is "Infomation" machine name "main" and second "About Me" machine name "about_me" and I want to create a page where other users can search for users with specific attributes in their "Information" or "About Me" profile. I'm just starting out with drupal 7.10 so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achived this by making a view called "Search Users". I couldn't figure out contextual filters so I tried using "Fields Criteria."

I first selected that I wanted the field to show users. Then I added the fields that I wanted. Then I added the field criteria that I wanted to filter by and check "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it." That was all I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using views contextual filters.

or you can use advanced search for users

```
http://www.yoursite.com/search/user
```

set the user permission accordingly to view advanced search